# Free Day planner web app

Tags: web-apps, productivity, scheduling

I'm looking for a web app that would allow me to quickly schedule my day for free.

The app should be able to simply assign events/task to specific times of the day that I could use as reference throughout the week. If possible, the web app should have the ability to display notifications/alerts when each new task approaches/ends.

For example, I should be able to assign an event say for example, "study linear algebra for 1 hr" at 6 a.m. for weekends and then be alerted that it's time to study and then that it's time to move onto the next task.

If no app exist, then I'll make one in Typescript.

Comment: Do you want to self-host the web app, or should it be hosted?

Comment: You might want to try out google calendar.   It has the new goals thing, and you could do something like that.

Comment: @unor it could be either, but hosted ones would be great for syncing across devices

Comment: @cybernard google calendar seems to be it! (It even has Reminders) Mind putting that as a answer so that I can approve it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend google calendar. It has the new goals thing, and you could do something like that.

user wants to schedule their time so calendar and web based is google calendar.
It definitely has notification, both automatic, and you can add/change reminders.

If you have a smart phone you can even use your voice command to create calendar events.